# PowerShell to display message if function ran successfully

Tags: powershell

I have a simple ps script to restart the process of windows explorer. I have this function to do so:

```bsh
Function Restart-Explorer()
{
    Stop-Process -ProcessName explorer
}

Function ranFunction
{
    if (Restart-Explorer) {
        "Success"
    }
    else {
        "failed"
    }
}
```

i just don't know how to display a pop up message if the function runs successfully or not.

Can someone point me in the right direction please? resources where i can learn this would be very helpful.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do both things inside one `Restart-Explorer` function.

The `Stop-Process` returns nothing unless the `PassThru` switch is given. Using that in combination with `ErrorAction SilentlyContinue`, you can examine afterwards if an object is returned (Success) or not (Failed).

Something like this:

```
function Restart-Explorer {
    $proc = Stop-Process -Name explorer -PassThru -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
    if ($proc) { 
        $msg = "Success"
        $icon = "Information"
    } 
    else { 
        $msg = "Failed"
        $icon = "Critical"
    }
    Add-Type -AssemblyName Microsoft.VisualBasic
    [Microsoft.VisualBasic.Interaction]::MsgBox($msg, "OKOnly,SystemModal,$Icon", "Restart Explorer")
}

Restart-Explorer
```

<sup>I'm using the `[Microsoft.VisualBasic.Interaction]::MsgBox()` method here, because it has an easy way of ensuring the dialog is topmost by adding `SystemModal`</sup>

Hope that helps

Comment: thanks for your response! this worked perfectly. Cheers

Comment: Thanks, I just noticed i had `notepad` in there instead of `explorer`. That was from testing on my machine. Fixed now

Answer (score 0):

If all you want is a pop-up the user needs to acknowledge with a message you can add the following to your code.

```
[System.Windows.MessageBox]::Show( 'Message here','Window Title','OK','Window Type[Information,Error,Warning]')
```

So applying to your scenario this would be my suggestion:

```
Function Restart-Explorer()
{
    Stop-Process -ProcessName explorer
}

Function ranFunction
{
    if (Restart-Explorer) {
        [System.Windows.MessageBox]::Show( 'Message Here','Some Title','OK','Information')
    }
    else {
        [System.Windows.MessageBox]::Show( 'Message Here','Some Title','OK','Error')
    }
}
```